# Change legend order and color in seaborn facetgrid

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am using seaborn facetgrid in combination with lineplot to produce:

Is there a way to change legend order from Average, Good, Poor to Poor, Average, Good and assign the color red to Poor and the color green to Good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `hue_order` to `map`:

```
orders = ['Poor', 'Average', 'Good']

arg = ['val', 'date', 'Condition']

(sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Year', col_wrap=1, height=5)
    .map(sns.lineplot, *arg, hue_order=orders)
    .add_legend()
    .set_titles("{col_name}")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of [Quang Hoang's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108584/9404057), you can also add the keyword `pallete` to control the colors:

```
orders = ['Poor', 'Average', 'Good']
palette = {'Poor': 'red', 'Average': 'blue', 'Good': 'green'}

arg = ['val', 'date', 'Condition']

(sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Year', col_wrap=1, height=5)
    .map(sns.lineplot, *arg, hue_order=orders, palette=palette)
    .add_legend()
    .set_titles("{col_name}")
)
```